# XSLT and XML content not loading in Microsft Edge and Internet Explorer Browsers Issue

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, xslt

I've noticed that the following JavaScript code doesn't seem to be loading any XML or XSLT data from their corresponding files into either Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge browsers, and I'm not sure what I've written incorrectly.

Below are the two JavaScript functions I am using to load the content..

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
    try {
        xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"
    } catch (err) {
    } // Helping IE11
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayXMLDoc(xml_file, xsl_file, element_id) {
    xml = loadXMLDoc(xml_file);
    xsl = loadXMLDoc(xsl_file);

    // BROWSER IS IE / EDGE.
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
        document.getElementById(element_id).innerHTML = ex;
    }
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        var resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
        document.getElementById(element_id).appendChild(resultDocument);
    }
}
```

And here is how these functions are being called...

```
<body onload="displayXMLDoc('myfile.xml', 'myfile.xsl', 'myoutput');">
```

**PLEASE NOTE:**

The code is currently working for all other browsers, for example, in FireFox and Chrome.

Comment: Well, Edge supports `XSLTProcessor`, and if you want to write code that checks for the support of that interface/object then you should of course check for it directly with e.g. `if (typeof XSLTProcessor !== 'undefined') { // now use XSLTProcessor here }` instead of checking unrelated stuff like `document.implementation` and assuming the existence of XSLT processor. As for IE, which versions of IE do you target? And do you get any error message in the IE or Edge console when the code fails?

Comment: `if (window.ActiveXObject)` as an "BROWSER IS IE / EDGE" check for instance is nonsense, neither IE 11 nor Edge will give true for that check.

Comment: For Chrome, Firefox and Edge you can use the approach used in http://plnkr.co/edit/Neqn90as6h9wUGg5qWNC?p=preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that current versions of Edge, Chrome and Firefox support `Promise` one approach these days is to use a library to have `Promise` support in IE and that way use promises to handle the asynchronous loading of the XML and XSLT documents. That way the code to load an XML document and and XSLT document and apply an XSLT transformation to get an HTML result, with an option to set some XSLT parameters, looks as follows:

```
 function loadDoc(url) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve) {
         var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
         req.open("GET", url);
         if (typeof XSLTProcessor === 'undefined') {
           try {
             req.responseType = 'msxml-document';
           }
           catch (e) {}
         }
         req.onload = function() {
           resolve(this.responseXML)
         }
         req.send();
       });
  }

  function transform(xmlUrl, xslUrl, xsltParams, targetElement) {
    Promise.all([loadDoc(xmlUrl), loadDoc(xslUrl)]).then(function(data) {
      var xmlDoc = data[0];
      var xslDoc = data[1];

      if (typeof XSLTProcessor !== 'undefined') {
        var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
        proc.importStylesheet(xslDoc);

        for (var prop in xsltParams) {
          proc.setParameter(null, prop, xsltParams[prop]);
        }

        var resultFrag = proc.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, targetElement.ownerDocument);

        targetElement.textContent = '';
        targetElement.appendChild(resultFrag);
      }
      else {
          var template = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XslTemplate.6.0');
          template.stylesheet = xslDoc;
          var proc = template.createProcessor();

          for (var prop in xsltParams) {
            proc.addParameter(prop, xsltParams[prop]);
          }

          proc.input = xmlDoc;

          proc.transform();

          var resultHTML = proc.output;

          targetElement.innerHTML = resultHTML;
      }
    });
  }
```

It can then be called as

```
transform('file.xml', 'input.xsl', { ids : 'test_value2'}, document.getElementById('d1'));
```

where the third argument is a Javascript objects with any parameters to set for the XSLT stylesheet, for instance if the XSLT is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- pass in a string with a single id value for the parameters ids or a '|' separated list of ids -->
    <xsl:param name="ids" select="''"/>

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="products/test[$ids = '' or contains(concat('|', $ids, '|'), id)]">
            <a href="#"> Hello # <xsl:value-of select="value"/></a>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then the above Javascript snippets sets that `ids` parameter.

An XML input sample is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>

    <test>
        <id>test_value1</id>
        <value>1</value>
    </test>

    <test>
        <id>test_value2</id>
        <value>2</value>
    </test>

</products>
```

Online sample working with current versions of IE, Edge, Chrome and Firefox on Windows 10 is at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/arcor-archive/2016/test2016081501.html.

A working code snippet is

```js
      function loadDoc(url) {
           return new Promise(function(resolve) {
             var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
             req.open("GET", url);
             if (typeof XSLTProcessor === 'undefined') {
               try {
                 req.responseType = 'msxml-document';
               }
               catch (e) {}
             }
             req.onload = function() {
               resolve(this.responseXML)
             }
             req.send();
           });
      }
      
      function transform(xmlUrl, xslUrl, xsltParams, targetElement) {
        Promise.all([loadDoc(xmlUrl), loadDoc(xslUrl)]).then(function(data) {
          var xmlDoc = data[0];
          var xslDoc = data[1];
          
          if (typeof XSLTProcessor !== 'undefined') {
            var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
            proc.importStylesheet(xslDoc);
            
            for (var prop in xsltParams) {
              proc.setParameter(null, prop, xsltParams[prop]);
            }
            
            var resultFrag = proc.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, targetElement.ownerDocument);
            
            targetElement.textContent = '';
            targetElement.appendChild(resultFrag);
          }
          else {
              var template = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XslTemplate.6.0');
              template.stylesheet = xslDoc;
              var proc = template.createProcessor();
              
              for (var prop in xsltParams) {
                proc.addParameter(prop, xsltParams[prop]);
              }
              
              proc.input = xmlDoc;
              
              proc.transform();
              
              var resultHTML = proc.output;
              
              targetElement.innerHTML = resultHTML;
          }
        });
      }
      
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        transform('http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/cdtest/test2016081501.xml', 'http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/cdtest/test2016081501.xsl', { ids : 'test_value2'}, document.getElementById('d1'));
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://www.promisejs.org/polyfills/promise-7.0.4.min.js"></script>

    <h1>Testing XSLT transformation</h1>
    <div id="d1"></div>
```